# How do I make every file in a static dir have Content-Type ... using express?

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers

I have a dir that contains anywhere between zero and a few hundre files, all without extension (generated in an unknowable nested dir structure by another app, with the writing occurring somewhere in a library that I can't, nor want, to modify code in), with all files containing html content. I'd like to use express's convenient `static` call so I don't have to worry about which files exist, but

```
app.use(express.static("..."))
```

does not let me say that all the content from this dir should be `Content-Type text/html`. Is there a way to to serve up content from anywhere in that dir (without knowing what's in it) with the response header always saying the content is text/html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, setting the default mime type to "text/html" so that express keeps infering the mime type when there is an extension but simply uses "text/html" when it has no idea which to pick was the solution:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();
...
express.static.mime.default_type = "text/html";
app.use(express.static(contentPath));
...
app.listen(...)
```